# How to call c# delegate from a c++ function that is hooked

Tags: c#, c++, delegates

What I want to do
I want to call a c# delegate from a hooked c++ function

I have found links that call c# delegate from c++ functions and it works fine. but I want to call the delegate from a hooked c++ function

What have i tried?

1. declared a delegate in c#
2. converted the delegate to function pointer using GetFunctionPointerForDelegate
3. passed the function pointer to c++
4. in c++ library, saved the pointer in a variable
5. the function in step 3 will hook "LdrInitializeThunk" which is the first method which is called anytime a remote thread is created. so we are continuously watching on this.
   When a remote thread is created, hooked function for LdrInitializeThunk gets fired
6. in this hooked method I am passing the pointer created in step 2 converting it to address and calling the delegate. This gives an access violation

If the callback function is directly called in step 3 it works fine. Issue is when its called from the hooked function.